# yum error on Centos 6.6

Tags: rpm, centos6, yum

After a failed "yum update", yum does not work.

If I try to launch "yum update" I get as a result:

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: dellsysid, fastestmirror
Setting up Update Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
Eg. $releasever is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/$releasever/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

I downloaded and tried to install "centos-release" but with error:

```
# rpm -Uvh centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64.rpm
error: centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: BAD
error: centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64.rpm cannot be installed
```

The strangest thing is:

```
# rpm -q rpm
package rpm is not installed
```

How can I fix the problem and run successfully yum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link was useful for me, check this:

https://techjourney.net/centos-yum-rpm-error-rpmts_hdrfromfdno-rpmdbnextiterator-header-v3-rsasha1-signature-key-id-bad/

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue for cents 6.6. Because the yum variable `$releasever` is not correctly expanded. Issue the following command you might see:

```
$ python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase();pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)'

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
{'arch': 'i686',
'basearch': 'i386',
'infra': 'stock',
'releasever': '$releasever',
'uuid': '19f9697d-6f4f-428a-848a-f317d7a880fb'}
```

The value of `releaser` should be `6` rather than `$releasever` in this case. So just set the variable to correct value and everything will be fine, with the following command:

```
echo 6 > /etc/yum/vars/releasever
```

Now you can check if it works:

```
$ python -c 'import yum, pprint; yb = yum.YumBase();pprint.pprint(yb.conf.yumvar, width=1)'

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
{'arch': 'i686',
'basearch': 'i386',
'infra': 'stock',
'releasever': '6',
'uuid': '19f9697d-6f4f-428a-848a-f317d7a880fb'}
```

Now yum command should work like a charm:)